# Calculate the sum of each table rows

Tags: javascript

I am having an application with functionality of showing tables for multiple stocks. If two stocks are present, two tables will be created dynamically as below.

Here two tables are present and I want to get the sum of `%change` in each year. ie sum of `%change` in 2015 from  both tables like `2014=7.88+1.69, 2015=-11.24+6.44` etc. Please help me to do. I need a solution using javascript.

[Link to Tables Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lK4Lu.png)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how the tables are formatted, you could write a function to look at the `<td>` tags that belong to the `%change` column and then sum the values in it. The 5th `<td>` of row 2 and on will have the numerical value in it.

Answer (score 0):

Set up a loop of all stock tables first..

```
var stocks = ["GE", "GOO"]; // stock codes, to use with table IDs
var num = stocks.length;
var years = {}; 
for(var loop = 0; loop < num; loop++){ // loop all of our stocks
 var tableID = "table_"+stocks[loop]; // make sure this matches tableid structure
 var table = document.getElementById(tableID); // get our table
 var rowNums = table.rows.length; // number of rows in table
 for(var rowLoop=1; rowNums: rowLoop++){ // skip first row (row 0)
  var row = table.rows[rowLoop]; // get the row 
  var year = row.cells[0].innerHTML;  // get text inside the cell 
  var change = rows.cells[5].innerHTML(); // get text inside the cell
  change = change.replace("%", ""); // remove % sign
  // Strip change percentage here
  // Make sure it is proper number that can be added 
  if(!years.year){
   years.year = change;
  } else {
   years.year += change; // do math to update year change amt 
  }
 }
}

 console.log(years);
```

I wrote this from my phone and it's 3:45am so I haven't had a chance to test it. Although I'm sure any errors could be easily fixed. This code and logic will do what you want. The only thing you have to do is actually remove the percentage signs and do some beta testing to ensure it works for you

You also need to make sure your tables have proper ID :)

SO really needs a code button for mobile... Spacebar 4 times on every line sucks

Comment: Thank you so much it really helped me

Comment: how do we get the text inside the cell. change variable returns a td element so how can we get the text inside that td. ? please help me. i am new to js.

Comment: Oh, I thought you knew a bit more JS. I am updating my code to get the text of the cell. Ok, I think the updated code should help a bit :)